# Can't set numbers on int[]

Tags: java, android, arrays, int

I have made a method that pass `int[]`, so in each position I want to set 4 numbers, here is what I did:

```
private void loadCars(int[] car){
    Json json = new Json(getApplicationContext());
    ArrayList<JSONObject> allCars;
    allCars = json.gettTodosLosJson();

    //Cargas los pictos desde el json
    //Seteamos el texto de las opciones
    Opcion1.setCustom_Img(json.getIcono(allCars .get(car[0])));
    Opcion2.setCustom_Img(json.getIcono(allCars .get(car[1])));
    Opcion3.setCustom_Img(json.getIcono(allCars .get(car[2])));
    Opcion4.setCustom_Img(json.getIcono(allCars .get(car[3])));
}
```

So, when I want to set the numbers for each car I do this:

```
loadCars(377,643,628,614);
```

but it doesn't work, it work if I set the method like `(int car1, int car2, int car3, int car4)` but I don't want to do it like that.

Comment: `loadCars(new int[]{377,643,628,614});`

Comment: or `private void loadCars(int... car) {`

Comment: If you always want four and only four integers, you might as well define four explicit integer parameters (like `loadCars(int int1, int int2, int int3, int int4)`). It might look less nice, but if someone uses your function with an array containing less than four integers, your code crashes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) in your method signature:

```
private void loadCars(int... car){
    //...
}
```

and then you can call it the way you want:

```
loadCars(377,643,628,614);
```

**EDIT**

But you have to consider @0xDEADC0DE's comment: if you always will require 4 integers then is better to use `loadCars(int int1, int int2, int int3, int int4)` to avoid undesirable results.

Comment: i have another method that is a random numer generator from 0 to 3 , so with those numbers i can select one of those ints , so thats why i needed to do it like this and not with int int1 , int int2 and so on